# How does the probability of staying positive depend on the diffusion coefficient?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two continuous martingales given as

$$X_t=z + \int_0^t a(s,X_s)\, dW_s,\quad \quad  Y_t=z + \int_0^t b(s,Y_s) \, dW_s,$$

where $z>0$, $a,b$ are Lipschitz and bounded functions s.t. $a(t,x),b(t,x)\ge 1$. Fix $T>0$. Do there exist $C, \alpha>0$ s.t.

$$|P(X_t>0)-P(Y_t>0)| \le Ct^\alpha \big(\|a-b \|_T + \operatorname{Lip}(a-b) \big),\quad \forall t\le T,$$

where $\|f\|_T:=\sup_{(t,x)\in [0,T]\times\mathbb R}|f(t,x)|$ and

$$\operatorname{Lip}(f):=\sup_{t\in [0,T]}\left \{ \sup_{x,y\in\mathbb R, x\neq y}\frac{|f(t,x)-f(t,y)|}{|x-y|} \right \}.$$

PS : According to the remark of mike, $z>0$ is specified to be fixed, and clearly $C$ may depend on $z$. If $a,b$ are only functions of $t$, then a straightforward computation yields $\alpha=1/2$.

PS2: I replace the initial condition $z>0$ by a random variable $Z$ which admits a density $h$ as good as possible. Set $L:=\|a-b \|_T + \operatorname{Lip}(a-b)\ge 0$. My idea is to use the following approximation argument. Following Euler's scheme, for each $n\ge 1$, define the approximating processes $X^n$ and $Y^n$: $X^n_0:=Z:=Y^n_0$ and

$$X^n_{i+1}:= X^n_{i} +a(t_i,X^n_{i})(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i})\equiv X^n_{i} +a_i(X^n_{i})(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}), \quad i=0,\ldots, n-1,$$
$$Y^n_{i+1}:= Y^n_{i} +b(t_i,Y^n_{i})(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i})\equiv Y^n_{i} +b_i(Y^n_{i})(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}), \quad i=0,\ldots, n-1,$$

where $t_i:=i\Delta t$, $\Delta t:=t/n$,  $a_i(\cdot):=a(t_i,\cdot)$ and $b_i(\cdot):=b(t_i,\cdot)$. Denote further by $f_i$ (resp. $g_i$) and $F_i$ (resp. $G_i$) the density and the cumulative distribution functions  of $X^n_i$ (resp. $Y^n_i$). Then $f_0=g_0$, $F_0=G_0$ and the recursive relation

$$f_{i+1}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\Delta t}a_i(z)}\exp\left(-\frac{(z-x)^2}{2\Delta t a_i(z)^2}\right)f_i(z)dz, \quad i=0,\ldots, n-1.$$

As $|P(X_T>0)-P(Y_T>0)|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|F_n(0)-G_n(0)|$ holds, it suffices to establish the inequality

$$|F_n(x)-G_n(x)|\le Ct^\alpha L,$$

uniformly in $n$. How can me obtain such an estimation by this iteration?

Comment: you want this to be uniform in z ?  I think there are problems for  z's on the order of sort(t), where the probabilities are on the order of 1.

Comment: Not necessarily. We may assume the constant $C$ depends on $z>0$. Do you know  how to show this dependence? I really look forward to that

Comment: @mike Could you please let me know the result or give me an outline if you know it? Thanks so much

Comment: Let $X_t$  be a brownian motion with variance $\sigma_X t$ etc., and $z = \sqrt(t)$.  The $P(X_t > 0) = \Phi(-1/\sigma_x)$. Then $P(X_t > 0 ) - P(Y_t > 0 ) $ doesn't converge to 0 as $t \rightarrow 0$, so the inequality can't hold uniformly in z for any $\alpha$

Comment: @mike Thanks for the reply. While, as I said, I don't pursue an estimation uniformly in $z$. More precisely, this constant $C$ is for some fixed $z$